# Is there any way (CSS, static resource?) to change the font size of all dynamic choices in Visual Flow?

Tags: css, visual-workflow, static-resources

I have been successful overriding the font size for different field labels but not the elements of my dynamic choice fields.

Answer (score 1):

If your flow is hosted in a visualforce page which I assume it is, you should be able to reach and style any of these elements from your flow.

The best thing you could do is view the rendered source of your page which hosts the flow, pick out the elements you want to style and add the CSS for it in your visualforce page like you would do to style any other regular visualforce page.